# Group the message in inbox according to the contact number

Tags: android, database, message

I want to modify an app of mine. It is a sms based app. In the inbox i want to view first the number of message which will be organised by the number of sender and then when i click any one of them wish to view the whole conversation with him.

Suppose, five contact has given me 20 msg. First i will show that in the inbox there is 5 item viewing by their name/phone number with the latest msg date and when i click any one of them it will show the whole conversation with him.

I have googled it though not get much help.May be it is the keyword which is the reason or not. From the google i have only learnt that i will have the msg if i query the by group.But it doesn't  work though they have said it won't work after android 4.0+ but i have test it with android 2.3 and alas it wasn't worked. Please help me out.